# error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. building a pipeline with azure and can't find csproj file

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, yaml, azure-pipelines

Hi I've got a solution that has multiple projects held within it where I'm hoping to automate the build and deployment of the webapplication within the project.

on my HD the dir looks like C:\Users\mleip\source\repos\edocs.utils.bluebeam-api\edocs.utils.bluebeam-api.Caller\edocs.utils.CDEComms , however, when I run the below yaml
i get

```
 MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.




trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet restore 
- powershell:  |
    Write-Host "Your parameter is now: $env:Param"
    Write-Host "When outputting standard variable build id: $(Build.BuildId)"
    Write-Host "When outputting standard variable build id via env: $env:BuildNumber"
    Write-Host "The repo name is: $(Build.Repository.Name)"
    Write-Host "The build definition name is: $(Build.DefinitionName)"
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects:  '**/edocs.utils.bluebeam-api.Caller/edocs.utils.CDEComms/edocs.utils.CDEComms.csproj'
```

So far I have tried several combinations of dir for where azure should locate the build file, however, each time it fails. The solution has several projects within it. CDEComms is the only project within that folder so I'm left quite confused as to what's going on.

I'm quite new to building pipelines and any help as to why this is failing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you run command locally, how's the result? If you simply specify `**/*.csproj` in the YAML file, will the build start? Did you create the YAML file under the correct repo? In addition, set variable `system.debug` to `True`, to check whether the path is correct in `C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build {path}`.

Comment: The Yaml was created by Azure when clicking creating pipeline. it's there default yaml with the addition of the small bit of PS.

Comment: Do you use Azure DevOps Service (https://dev.azure.com/xxxx)? Where did you store the repo?

Comment: The repo is dev.azure.com/xxx/edocs.utils.bluebeam-api/_git/edocs.utils.bluebeam-api

Comment: This means you are using Azure DevOps Service. Then try to  simply specify `**/*.csproj `in the YAML file to check the build result. And set variable `system.debug` to `True`, to check whether the path is correct in `C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build {path}`.  Also, clone the repo to your local machine to run build it locally, to check the result.

Comment: Any update to this issue?

Comment: I used your advice and was able to see what was happening at what stage in the build pipeline thank you for pointing me in the right direction with the debug tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to narrow down the issue, try to simply specify `**/*.csproj` in the YAML file to check the build result. And set variable `system.debug` to `True`, to check whether the path is correct in `C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe build {path}`. Also, clone the repo to your local machine to run build it locally, to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

From the description you have provided, you will first have to push your code/solution i.e. the  content of your C:\ drive to your repository.

Comment: The repo  is in azure with the dir edocs.utils.bluebeam-api\edocs.utils.bluebeam-api.Caller\edocs.utils.CDEComms. the repo has all the files required to build the project and others have been able to pull the repo.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "script" line to use the path of your project

 `- script: dotnet build your_rep/path _to_the_solution_you_are_building/yoursolution.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration) `